# C# Large JSON to string causes out of memory exception

Tags: c#, json, string, out-of-memory

I'm trying to download very large JSON file. However, I keep getting an error message:

**"An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"**

**{The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception.}**

Any tips how I can download this large JSON filet? I have tried to use string and StringBuilder but no luck.

Here is my code:

```
public static string DownloadJSON(string url)
{
 try
 {
   String json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url); // This part fails!
   return json;
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
  throw;
 }
}
```

I have created console application. I have tried this code with smaller JSON file and it worked. 
My idea is later to split this larger JSON file and put it to database. However I need to encode it before I can put it to database. I have not write yet database part or anything else, because downloading this big JSON causes problems. I don't need it as a stream, but that was my example way how I made encoding. I need to encode it because data have special characters like å.

I tried also this but same problem:

```
var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            var response = http.GetResponse();

            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Why do you need it as a stream? Why are you using `Encoding.Unicode`? (That's going to be twice as large as UTF-8 for ASCII text.) How large is the text? What are you doing with it afterwards? Why do you have a `try`/`catch` block where you're just rethrowing?

Comment: I'm not sure how big it is... How I can measure it? I can open it using browser but...

Comment: Can you collect it as a stream, instead of a string?  Try OpenRead instead of DownloadString.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have very very large response. It is better to process stream. Now comes to point that cause outofmemoryexcetion.

- In .net max size of any object 2GB. This is even for 64 bit machine. If your machine is 32 bit then this limit is very low.

In your case above rules get break so it will not work but if you have file size less than that then try to build your code against 64 bit and it will give your result.

Comment: Thank you, I rebuild my code against 64 bit and now it works! =)
However, if I want to use later 32 bit, what is the best way handle 450MB JSON file?

Comment: 450 MB file can be handle with 32 bit but problem is that your program is doing many other thing apart from this.I suggest one solution that build console application that just download json file and launch process from your existing application so new process have its own memory space so it download that file and later you can manuplate that file but it still depend on How your current program works.

Answer (score 0):

Download it to a file:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(
        url,
        path);
}
```

Of course it could be not handled by JSON libraries if it's too big to open in memory, but you can try to process it somehow if you don't have a choice and file must be so big.

Comment: Thank you, I download it using your example. File size was 450MB, so it's not so big as I expected. But enough big to cause problems for me.